# How to provide only Access for ELMAH.axd for Administrator login in web

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, elmah

I have created application and implemented ELMAH logging. In my site there are three types of users.

**Admin** : can everything (rights to view elamh.axd)

**User**  : can have own rights (can't view elamh.axd)

**Guest** : only view (can't view elamh.axd)

The above user will be stored in Database.

**Probelm:-**
Now how could i manage protection level for User and Guest to view ELMAH.axd log file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using [Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ab2fxh0.aspx) you can add this to your web.config:

```
<location path="~/elmah.axd">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Admin" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

If you're not using roles you will have to specify each user you want to give access to:

```
<location path="~/elmah.axd">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="user1, user2, user3" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

**Update:**

As you aren't using any of the built in authentication/authorisation and you don't have control of the elmah page you're going to have to handle the `BeginRequest()` event:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if(Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("elmah.axd"))
    {
        // Check if user can see elmah and handle unauthorised users (return 401/redirect to login page/etc...)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. **I am handling user with Sessions**, so how this would be work with namespace  **System.Web.Mvc and HttpSessionStateBase**

Comment: Are you using asp.net membership?

Comment: No i am using  **Session["UserName"] = "Admin;** in Asp.Net MVC 3.0

Comment: Sorry to dig up a very old question, but this solution doesn't work - at the point that Application_BeginRequest() fires, the Session variables have not been set up, meaning you can't check to see the username. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Authentication also hasn't been performed at this point. You can try an event later in the request cycle. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication_events(v=vs.110).aspx