# How do i restrict access to elmah without using in-built authentication?

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I have configured elmah and it works fine .I have also started seeing the benefits of using such a tool.
Now ,i just want a few people to have access to the elmah.axd file and i would like to authenticate them if possible before allowing them access to the file.How can i do that without using asp.net built in authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phil Haack [wrote](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/07/24/securely-implement-elmah-for-plug-and-play-error-logging.aspx) about it long time ago.

First of all you can add **admin** to the path attribute in the section of the ELMAH HttpHandler:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="/admin/elmah.axd" 
    type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
</httpHandlers>
```

and then restrict access for anonymous to that folder:

```
<location path="admin">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Some more infos [here](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages).

Comment: the authorization mechanism you mentioned is the built-in asp.net authorization one ???if so,i have already said in my question ,that i don't use this authentication mechanism.

Comment: The link is dead:  http://codingpowers.wordpress.com/ is marked private by its owner

Answer (score 0):

It seems an old question

[How to provide only Access for ELMAH.axd for Administrator login in web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005389/how-to-provide-only-access-for-elmah-axd-for-administrator-login-in-web)

has provided me with the answer

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if(Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("elmah.axd"))
    {
        // Check if user can see elmah and handle unauthorised users (return 401/redirect to login page/etc...)
    }
}
```